# jQuery do something when class has added class

Tags: jquery, show, each, attr

I have a `li` with class 'tab3'. There is jQuery elsewhere that when you hover on it it adds the class 'selected'.  I want to do something when this happens:

```
<li class='tab3 selected'>
  <div class='showme'>Show this</div>
  <div class='addattr'>Add attributes</div>
</li>

$('.tab3.selected').each(function() {
    $('.showme').show();
    $('.addattr').attr('style', 'position:relative; display:block');
});
```

Comment: You need to find where the hover function is and append your code there.  OR implement another hover function binding yourself.

Comment: That's really not the right way to set the "style" on an element. Look up the jQuery ".css()" method and use that. Setting it that way may not even work (in some browsers).

Comment: Pointy, below, has given you the best answer as far as jQuery is concerned. However, first: your example, by itself, has some flaws: the divs are already showing (unless showme has a css of display:none); second, if both showme and addattr have css of display:none; the hover will never occur since the entire li is hidden. Geehs, so many variances here; and, finally, css:hover is the best way to handle simple things like those.

Comment: on a side note, you don't need "each()", as jquery is transveral. this will do                
`$('.tab3.selected .showme').show();
$('.tab3.selected .addattr').css('position', 'relative').css('display', 'block');` Moreover, it's better to create a class for `position:relative; display:block`, as well as a css rule in your stylesheet. by example class "relblock", so you can use `$('.tab3.selected .addattr').addClass('relblock');` which spare  you a redraw too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish this via css:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .tab3 .showme{display:none;}
    .tab3.selected .showme{display:block;}
</style>
```

Comment: i like this approach, and [here is a fiddle to play with it](http://jsfiddle.net/Nrvfw/)

Answer (score 3):

There's no built-in way to do that, but you can always register an event handler for a "custom" event like "class-change", and then trigger that whenever you update an element's class. (You could even redefine the "addClass" function to do that.)

```
$('whatever').addClass('selected').trigger('class-change');

// ...

$('.tab3').bind('class-change', function() {
  $('.tab3.selected').each(function() {
    $('.showme').show();
    $('.addattr').attr('style', 'position:relative; display:block');
  });
});
```

Of course you should also consider using plain old CSS rules to make appearances change when adding/removing classes, as noted in @Brad Wedell's answer.

Comment: huh? why not call the changes directly in the hover bind then? If he does not have access to the hover binding function which adds the selected class, I don't see he can trigger the class change on addClass().

Comment: The idea is that by simply triggering an event, the code that changes the class doesn't have to know about the particulars of the other code.  It's a de-coupling technique. To trigger the "class-change" event in "addClass()" would require that the stock "addClass()" be replaced with a wrapper.

Comment: yes, but still, the main idea remains. If he doesn't have access to the function that binds hover to perform addClass, he can't trigger the custom event. If does have access, then of course this is an elegant way ;)

Comment: Ah yes, that's true. I assumed it's all one application and that it's all open to being refined.  Otherwise, you're right - the only thing to do is simply run the desired code at the point the classes are added. If even that's impossible, then CSS is probably all that's left, or possibly an interval timer to update the page (yuk).